# How fetch all rows which are 10 min apart in single query in PHP MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, datetime, recursive-query

I have table *device* which contain temperature values recorded and their time of measurement .I need to sample this data by fetching only values that are at least 10 min apart .(
ex  if first row  reads    (30k,8.40.00) then next row contain value after or at 8.50.00  ( whichever is next 10 minutes values) .
my time column is stored as sting format (H.m.s).
my current select query in PHP is

```
$sql="select value ,time from device where time >= '$interval' order by time limit 1";
```

Using strtotime method, $interval value is increased by 10 min . each time selecting only one row

Problem is that I need to use a loop to fetch all rows possible. My question is how can  get all rows without using a loop ,like in a single query ?  For using a for loop I need t know number of rows in advance.

Comment: It may be better to use 1 SQL loop, reading them all in time order.  Then in your PHP loop you can check for the time against `$interval` and ignore it if it isn't past the value.

Comment: Tricky task, It occurred to me when I was doing analytics of visited users and needed to separate them by 10min interval to track bouncing visits. I need to check how I solved it that time to help you here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more complicated than you think. You cannot just look over intervals between consective rows, you need to keep track of the last row that was selected to identify the next one. This implies an iterative process; in SQL, this is usually implemented using a recursive query - which MySQL supports starting version 8.0 only.

Consider:

```
with recursive cte as (
    select value, time 
    from device 
    where time = (select min(time) from device)
    union all
    select d.value, d.time 
    from cte c
    inner join device d on d.time = (
        select min(d1.time) from device d1 where d1.time >= c.time + interval 10 minute
    )
)
select * from cte
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest first using window functions to get the value for each row that is 10 minutes later (at least) and then applying the recursive subquery:

```
with recursive d(value, time, next_time) as (
      select value, time,
             min(time) over (order by time
                             range between interval 10 minute following and unbounded following
                            ) as next_time
      from device
     )
     recursive cte(value, time, next_time) as (
      (select value, time, next_time
       from d 
       order by time
       limit 1
      ) union all
      select d.value, d.time, d.next_time
      from cte join
           d 
           on device.time = cte.next_time
      )
select *
from cte;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=473b6bc5024b2dba8ed736ab53305207) is a db<>fiddle.

Answer (score -1):

I think that would work:

```
$sql="select `value`,`time` from `device` where MINUTE(`time`) IN (0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50) order by `time`";
```

If you have multiple value by 10 minutes and just want one, use a group by MINUTE(`time`)

Comment: This just assumes the events happen at fixed times in the hour.  Even if you made them relative to a specific time, what if an event happened 11 minutes after that time.

Comment: try that: $sql="select `value`,`time`, minute(`timestamp`) from `device` where MINUTE(`time`) IN ('0%', '1%', '2%', '3%', '4%', '5%') order by `time` group by minute(`timestamp`) "; Its not clear from your question if your want one per 10 minutes interval (which i understood) or just get an around 10 minutes and start back 10 minutes after the last value fetched.